# Understanding the notation of uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I'm currently struggling my way through Real Analysis and I don't know how to "read" the notation for a uniform norm.

> $\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{\infty}:=\sup_{x \in X}|f(x)|$

Could someone please break down the meaning of each symbol and the information it is trying to tell me? I'll outline were I'm specifically confused,

For $\left\lVert f\right\rVert_{\infty}$, the double verticle bars represents the norm or "length" of vector within a Euclidean Space. So we would have the length of the function $f$. But what is the meaning and purpose of the subscript infinity? What information is this suppose to tell me?

For $\sup_{x \in X}|f(x)|$, $\sup$ is the lowest upper bound of some value. So we have the lowest upper bound for the absolute value of the function $f(x)$. But what is the meaning of the subscript ${x \in X}$?

The final question is how both these statements are equal but I first need to know the purpose of the notation to answer that.

Comment: Notice that $:=$ means equal *by definition*, so there is no equality to show, we are *defining* $\|f\|_{\infty}$ to mean $\sup_{x \in X}|f(x)|$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ is the lowest upper bound of the set
\begin{equation}
\{|f(x)|, x\in X\}\subset {\mathbb R}
\end{equation}
The $\infty$ in the norm notation comes from the fact that for a collection of numbers $f_1\cdots f_n$ one has
\begin{equation}
\max_i |f_i| = \lim_{p\to \infty} \left(\sum_i |f_i|^p\right)^{1/p}
\end{equation}
Its purpose is to differentiate this particular norm from other function norms that could be defined on $X$. It is a cultural element.

Comment: You've introduced more complicated notation to explain another notation. That doesn't help me understand the information each symbol in the uniform norm definition is trying to tell me. I don't know what $\max_i |f_i| = \lim_{p\to \infty} \left(\sum_i |f_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$ is supposed to represent.

Comment: For example for 2 numbers, $\max(|f_1|, |f_2|) = \lim (|f_1|^p + |f_2|^p)^{1/p}$ when $p$ tends to infinity. That's where the notation comes from because this latter quantity is denoted $\|\cdot\|_p$. For example $(2^{1000} + 3^{1000})^{0.001}$ is very close to 3, the maximum of 2 and 3.

Comment: Again, you're simply stating notations without explaining what they actually mean. How would you explain these concepts verbally while noting the purpose of each symbol? Also remember the whole purpose of my question is that I don't know how to interrupt the definition of a uniform norm. I don't know what literal meaning it has because the notation is nonsense to me.

Comment: The meaning is that of the lowest upper bound of all the values of $|f(x)|$ when $x$ varies in $X$. The notation $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is conventional. There is nothing more to understand.